# Use Sass in Saber

Tags: css, sass

**Goal**

I'd rather enjoy using Sass in the Saber framework, which it supports. Here are [the docs](https://saber.land/docs/css-preprocessors.html#sass--scss) for it if you wish. Simple, right?

**Problem**

```sh
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
```

My code is extremely vanilla at this stage.

**Context**

I did this:

```sh
yarn add sass-loader sass --dev
```

And initially did that:

```js
// saber-config.js

module.exports = {
  build: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/scss/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...which resulted in no styles. *M'kay*. So I removed that part and imported the styles directly into the layout component, like so—

```html
<!-- layouts/page.vue -->

<style lang="scss">
@import url('../scss/main.scss');
</style>
```

That's the point at which the aforementioned error occurs. What's also interesting is that if I move the Sass code from `main.scss` to the `page.vue` `<style>` tags, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was a Sass version issue. I resolved it by bumping down a version.

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "saber": "^0.11.7",
  "saber-plugin-feed": "^0.4.3",
  "saber-plugin-query-posts": "^0.4.6",
  "sass": "^1.22.12",
  "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
}
```